# list iterator as way to access and modify std:list content

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, stdlist

Say you have list

**NTlist** (abstractly represented here):

```
     ["string2", RHSlist ]<-->["string1", RHSlist ]<-->["string3", RHSlist ]
```

Now, you search for the element of `NTlist` containing "string1" using a list iterator, **NTlocation**.  As a result of search, `NTlocation` then "points" to the middle element.

The goal is to add to this middle element's RHSlist.  I do that with:

```
 NTlocation->RHSlist.push_back(RHSentry); //where RHSentry is of type RHSnode.
```

**The question**:
Why is the middle element's RHSlist not updated? Rather, it is the iterator NTlocation that has it's own RHSlist that is updated.

Thanks for your time.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct RHSnode {
string token;
} RHSnode;

typedef struct NTnode {
string token;
list<RHSnode> RHSlist;
} NTnode;

list<NTnode>::iterator searchNTList(string NTstring, list<NTnode> &NTlist);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
 list<NTnode> NTlist;
 list<NTnode>::iterator NTlocation;

// making three entries in NTList
NTnode entry1;
entry1.token = "string2";
NTlist.push_back(entry1);

NTnode entry2;
entry2.token = "string1";
NTlist.push_back(entry2);

NTnode entry3;
entry3.token = "string3";
NTlist.push_back(entry3);

RHSnode RHSentry;
RHSentry.token = "RHSentry";

//Now, say, I want to put this RHSentry (above) into NTlist with
// element that has it's token as "string1"
// so I search NTlist for token with "string1"
// and remember the NTlist element location with iterator NTlocation
 NTlocation = searchNTList("string1", NTlist);

// Now here's where the problem occurs
 NTlocation->RHSlist.push_back(RHSentry);

return 0;
}

list<NTnode>::iterator searchNTList(string NTstring, list<NTnode> &NTlist){
//"past-the-end" indications search failure
list<NTnode>::iterator NTlocation = NTlist.end();

list<NTnode>::iterator iterator = NTlist.begin();

for ( ; iterator != NTlist.end() ; iterator++ ){

    if (iterator->token.compare(NTstring) == 0){
        NTlocation = iterator;
        break;
    }

}
 return NTlocation;
}
```

Comment: *"Now here's where the problem occurs"* What problem occurs here? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ?

Comment: **From the text:  "Why is the middle element's RHSlist not updated? Rather, it is the iterator NTlocation that has it's own RHSlist that is updated."**  So to clarify, problem: middle element's RHSlist not updated. Expected outcome:  middle element's RHSlist updated.  Observe: Rather, it is the iterator NTlocation that has it's own RHSlist that is updated.  How they differ: middle element's RHSlist is not updated.   Iterator NTlocation has it's own RHSlist that is updated.

Comment: *"Why is the middle element's RHSlist not updated?"* What makes you believe it isn't? How do you determine that? *" it is the iterator NTlocation that has it's own RHSlist that is updated"* This statement makes no sense.  The iterator doesn't have any members, named `RHSlist` or otherwise. It points to a node in the list - it is this node that's being updated. I'm not sure what else you could possibly expect.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, looking at `entry2` and expecting it to be modified? It won't be. `NTlist.push_back(entry2)` makes a copy of `entry2` and places that copy into the list. It is this copy that the iterator points to, this copy that is being updated. The original, of course, remains unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the interest, Igor.  When I run a debugger, the middle element's RHSlist is not updated.  NTlocation "points" to some RHSlist, and the debugger is showing that that RHSlist is updated, not the middle one that I want.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, push_back(entry2) will place that copy into the list.  My question is how to search for the location of the list so that I can push_back into it. Meaning, I use a list iterator search for a specific entry.  I then find that entry and push_back some data into it's RHSlist.  Let me know if there is still confusion.

Comment: The node that `NTlocation` points to is in fact the node in the middle of the list. I don't understand what other node you expect to be affected.

Comment: Yes, I want it to point to the middle node. That is my intention.  I then want to push_back to the middle node's RHSlist.  But this is not what happens.  This is my problem.

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/XRU47837). I don't know what you are looking at, but whatever it is, you are misinterpreting what you see.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I still see no size in any of the RHSlists at the end of the code.  So the problem is my debugger, not my code? http://i.stack.imgur.com/C0AiH.jpg

Comment: I suppose. I'm not familiar with the IDE you are using. The code clearly works, and produces expected output - that's all I can say.